# Can JetBrain's DotTrace Performance Pro 5.3 be used again DiscountASP servers? Anyone with experience with this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dottrace, discountasp

The new DotTrace Performance Pro V5.3 now can connect to remote processes over HTTP, so I should be able to use it against my sites hosted on DiscountASP. Does anyone have experience of this. Hopefully it does work?

Thanks,

Comment: Having thought about this, I believe this is not possible since DotTrace requires a remote console agent to be run off the server called "RemoteAgent.exe" and without RDP I cannot see how this will run, and of course DiscountASP is shared hosting, so no RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use DiscountASP, and in fairness their support is really good - raise a ticket with them regarding the question, and you usually get a reply within 24hrs.

They also have a knowledge base: https://support.discountasp.net/KB/browse.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this. Good to hear about your good experience. I did get an answer back and as expected on Shared Hosting this is not allowed. So I am looking at a VPS solution, or trying to get my performance monitor to work without using an exe agent on the server. Awaiting reply from suppiers.